# Heroku is automatically upgrading python library to latest version [Docker container deploy]

Tags: docker, heroku, pyparsing, heroku-cli

Hello there i am trying to deploy a sample TensorFlow object-detection api application on Heroku using Heroku container my issue is that object-detection api uses version 2.4.2 of pyparsing but Heroku is automatically upgrading it to 3.0.9 which causes application to crash
I have confirmed library version on my local image and it is 2.4.2
[(local image version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgmGO.png) 
but when i run bash Console on Heroku it shows version 3.0.9
[(heroku pushed version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czqYw.png)

As of docker file I have tried both

```
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir httplib2 \
               pyparsing==2.4.2
```

and

```
RUN pip3 install --upgrade --no-cache-dir pip && \
    pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt:

```
httplib2 
pyparsing==2.4.2
```

due to this difference in library version my app crashes with error:

```
AttributeError: module 'pyparsing' has no attribute 'downcaseTokens'
```

gist:: [Complete Dockerfile and Error gist](https://gist.github.com/FawadAbbas12/8ab308cacbeb3aa349854ed0489e4b28)

I have also verified that any base docker layer is not updating that specific library.

So is there any way to make sure Heroku is using specified version of library available in docker image and not automatically update it ?

Comment: Have you considered upgrading your pyparsing code to be 3.0.9-compatible? The docs give you guidelines on how to address API changes and discontinued features: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/pyparsing_3.0.9/docs/whats_new_in_3_0_0.rst#other-discontinued-features

Comment: I had but it is being used in `googleapiclient` libraries so if i only upgrade gcp library for which that error is resolved it brakes other dependencies.

Comment: You can convert this call to `pyparsing.common.downcaseTokens`, and it will be compatible with both 2.4.2 and 3.0.9. Review the pyparsing CHANGES document for other compatibility notes. https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/CHANGES

Comment: Thanks for reply i had solved it by following the docs you mentioned earlier.
I just want to know why libraries are being automatically upgraded in my docker image on heroku where as on my local one they are of same version as i installed them.